# Can't deploy docker to heroku

Tags: php, docker, heroku

I want to deploy a docker image and then run it on Heroku. I don't want to use the GitHub or GitHub actions way.

The app is a simple PHP image.

On local, it runs fine.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
COPY index.php /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
RUN php index.php
```

`index.php` has:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

My heroku.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: php index.php
```

I'm following [this tutorial.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#getting-started)

The steps I have followed are:

My directory:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── heroku.yml
└── index.php

0 directories, 3 files
```

```
$ heroku login

$ heroku create -a app-name

$ heroku git:remote -a URL
```

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add all"
```

```
heroku stack:set container
```

```
git push heroku master
```

My docker run command(to run the container) would look like:

```
docker run -dit -p 80:80 php8.1
```

My error log looks like this:

```
2022-05-22T13:28:45.772758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c bundle\ exec\ puma\ -C\ config/puma.rb`
2022-05-22T13:28:46.470875+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found
2022-05-22T13:28:46.581715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-05-22T13:28:46.623321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-22T13:28:46.627920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-22T13:28:51.947957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c bundle\ exec\ puma\ -C\ config/puma.rb`
2022-05-22T13:28:52.620588+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found
2022-05-22T13:28:52.736634+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-05-22T13:28:52.790719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-22T13:28:53.541247+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=abcxz.herokuapp.com request_id=37a9ecc3-14c1-43b2-b4aa-2a4c105e4bc7 fwd="122.177.111.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-22T13:28:53.759520+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=abcxz.herokuapp.com request_id=8c68618c-b9c1-40c3-a436-35fa664fa891 fwd="122.177.111.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-22T13:28:54.824801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abcxz.herokuapp.com request_id=4974bd97-0abc-4c0d-943f-2a55fec94048 fwd="122.177.111.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: The `cmd` in your heroku.yml file tries to run a Ruby program (.rb extension), so I doubt it'll work with PHP. The error message you get complain about not being able to find a program called `bundle` which is also a Ruby thing.

Comment: sorry I have changed it already with a PHP command and the error remains the same
@HansKilian . SO ain't allowing me to edit now

Comment: Your log is still showing the 'bundle' error. Can you please update it with what it looks like now?